# Getting includes is not a function unexpectedly

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the microphone is connected and we can record audio like this:

```js
// Check Mic
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
    .then(stream => {
     // Code if Mic is available
     console.log('mic works');

     }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
        if(err.includes("Requested device not found")){
           console.log('No Mic Connected');
        } else if (err.includes("Permission denied")) {
           console.log('User denied the Permission to record');
        } else {

        }     
});
```

But Unexpectedly I get this error each time:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: err.includes is not a function

What I'm missing and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because `err` is actually an object, and an object does not have the prototype `includes`. The recommended way to check what kind of error it is, is to actually check `err.name`. [`MediaDevices.getUserMedia()` returns a known list of error names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia#Exceptions):

- `AbortError`
- `NotAllowedError`
- `NotFoundError`
- `NotReadableError`
- `OverconstrainedError`
- `SecurityError`
- `TypeError`

```js
// Check Mic
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    // Code if Mic is available
    console.log('mic works');
  }).catch(err => {
    switch (err.name) {
      case 'NotFoundError':
        console.log('No Mic Connected');
        break;
        
      case 'NotAllowedError':
        console.log('User denied the Permission to record');
        break;
    }
  });
```

If you want to check what the actual error message is, you should access it via `err.message`. Note that different browsers/user agents may have different messages, so I wouldn't consider this the best solution:

```js
// Check Mic
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
  .then(stream => {
    // Code if Mic is available
    console.log('mic works');
  }).catch(err => {
    const message= err.message;
    if (message.includes("Requested device not found")) {
      console.log('No Mic Connected');
    } else if (message.includes("Permission denied")) {
      console.log('User denied the Permission to record');
    }
  });
```

---

Of course, you can also always to `err.toString()`, but that's not the ideal solution.

Comment: Thanks ... would you recommend only check `==` instead of `includes`. it seems that the message is always the exact text ...

Comment: @foxer I've updated my answer: it is actually safer to check against `err.name`, because that is consistent across browsers. The message itself may vary from one browser to another.

Answer (score -1):

If err is `undefined` you will get a TypeError. Check for its existence like:

`if(err && err.includes("Requested device not found")){}`

Comment: `err` won't be `undefined`

Comment: My bad I didnt realise its not a ```String```